# Gpath when an expression is true

Tags: groovy, gpath

From the JSON below, I am trying to write a Gpath that will only return the "state" field when the "type" field is equal to *ride_state* (i.e. I just want the two "open" states)

```
[{
    "type": "day",
    "data": {
        "id": "7a46a975-5474-4278-a56f-4deadd9a276d",
        "state": "closed"
    }
}, {
    "type": "ride_state",
    "data": {
        "id": "13f3b625-b39e-4875-b29c-0173712b3c87",
        "state": "open"
    }
}, {
"type": "ride_state",
    "data": {
        "id": "b52b5081-e1df-42da-ba76-027c63205f8e",
        "state": "open"
     }
}]
```

I am new to Groovy and Gpath and so far haven't been able to find a way to do this, could anyone please help?

Comment: please add what you have tried so far; even if not working, it shows actual efford and it would make writing solutions easier.

Comment: This is not a valid json.

Comment: Sorry, the original JSON was much bigger so I cut most of it out and forgot the closing brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a valid json, this can be done as below:

```
def jsonString = """
[{
    "type": "day",
    "data": {
        "id": "7a46a975-5474-4278-a56f-4deadd9a276d",
        "state": "closed"
    }
}, {
    "type": "ride_state",
    "data": {
        "id": "13f3b625-b39e-4875-b29c-0173712b3c87",
        "state": "open"
    }
}, {
    "type": "ride_state",
    "data": {
        "id": "b52b5081-e1df-42da-ba76-027c63205f8e",
        "state": "open"
    }
}]
"""

assert new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
                      .parseText( jsonString )
                      .findResults {it.type == 'ride_state' ? it.data.state : null} == 
                      ['open', 'open']
```